# Strange permission issue [media server]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, btrfs, apparmor

I've been using my Linux machine (Ubuntu - 19.04 based) as a media server which has worked flawlessly so far - but suddenly I've been getting permission issues.

I'm running the media server (currently Jellyfin, but this issue also persists with Plex - so I think the fault isn't in the server) off a NAS drive formatted with two BtrFS subvolumes - one I use for backup and the other for the media files.

After changing some permissions in the backups subvolume (the two are both top level), all media software is suddenly getting denied, although the permissions are intact.
I've changed permissions to what they were before just in case (using chown and chmod, both recursive), but the issue persists.
Here are my permissions (my user is shmick and the media subvolume is Med-Vol):

```
> # file: Med-Vol/
> # owner: shmick
> # group: shmick user::rwx group::r-x other::r-x
```

This has worked flawlessly before.
syslog complains about lack of permissions still:

```
jellyfin[1335]: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Med-Vol' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
```

Plex has thrown in the same error as well.
I've also checked the AppArmor logs, which show no complaints.
I could not figure out what is wrong.
Is there anything I'm missing here? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Under what user is jellyfin running?

Comment: It's running under a dedicated user (also named jellyfin). I've also tried to change it to the owner with no luck.

Comment: The immutable attribute bit didn't get set somehow, did it?  What does `lsattr problemFileOrDir` show?